# Update hashed password in Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want the user to be able to update his own password. i get three inputs while in database i have the password field together with the username and email. I don't really know the flow of controller hope u can help me out.

my controller:

```
public function changepass() {

    $user = Auth::user();
    $rules = array(
        'old_password' => 'required|alphaNum|between:4,16',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|between:4,16|confirmed'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::action('HomeController@getpass', $user->id)->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        if (!Hash::check(Input::get('old_password'), $user->password)) {
            return Redirect::action('HomeController@getpass', $user->id)->withErrors('Old password does not match!');
        } else {
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::action('HomeController@getpass', $user->id)->withMessage("Password has been changed successfully!");
        }
    }
```

My view:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')

<div class="span8 well" style="opacity: 0.9">

<h4>Change password: </h4>

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'changepass/', 'method'=>'POST')) }}

{{Form::hidden('id',Auth::user()->id)}}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::password('old_password', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Old Password')) }}<br>
    {{ Form::password('new_password', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'New Password')) }}<br>
    {{ Form::password('confirm_new_password', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Confirm New Password')) }}
</div>

{{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}


</div>
@stop
```

//Route

```
 Route::post('changepass', 'HomeController@changepass');
```

Comment: It should be `if(Hash::check())` not `!Hash::check()`

Comment: What is the problem?